# UI/UX Software To Replace Fireworks

Tags: web-development, vector-graphics

I'm trying to get myself back upto speed when it comes to web development. I was recently forced to upgrade to Windows 10 from Vista SP2 due to stability problems.

Up until that point I was still using Adobe CS3, primarily Dreamweaver & Fireworks. Now that I've updated I've found I can use Atom to code but I'm having a really hard time finding anything comparable to Fireworks.

My workflow tends to be similar to Mike Lockes, demonstrated in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VttPLYvC8Kk

Is there any suggestions on what would work well for me on Windows 10?

I've saw good reviews for sketch but that's Mac only. And on software comparison sites I haven't found any that looks or sounds suitable.

Comment: I guess by the lack of answers Fireworks, although out dated, is still the best option